# Inexplicable node.js http throwing connect ECONNREFUSED (IPv6?)

Tags: node.js, ipv6, node.js-connect

I am running node.js as follows:

```
> http = require('http')
> http.get('http://myhost.local:8080',
    function (res) { console.log("RES" + res) }
  ).on('error', function (e) { console.log("Error:", e) })

> uri = require('url').parse("http://myhost.local:8080")
{ protocol: 'http:',
  slashes: true,
  auth: null,
  host: 'myhost.local:8080',
  port: '8080',
  hostname: 'myhost.local',
  hash: null,
  search: null,
  query: null,
  pathname: '/',
  path: '/',
  href: 'http://myhost.local:8080/' }
> http.get(uri,
    function (res) { console.log("RES" + res) }
  ).on('error', function (e) { console.log("Error:", e) })
```

An error is thrown for both the implicit and explicitly parsed URI and I get the following output for both:

> Error: { [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED]
>     code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
>     errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
>     syscall: 'connect' }

The host `myhost.local` is an alias for `localhost` in `/etc/hosts`, being:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost myhost.local myhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost myhost.local myhost
fe80::1%lo0 localhost myhost.local myhost
```

*EDIT*: I tried virtually every permutation for the hosts file, including the most obvious:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost 
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost myhost.local myhost
fe80::1%lo0 localhost
```

*EDIT* I should also mention that I have tried this on more than one Mac now.

Although it seems this is a rather common error, I have seen no useful explanations or workarounds. Here are some notable related facts:

1. Running `$ wget http://myhost.local:8080` works as expected, so it isn't a firewall problem.
2. Running `$ telnet myhost.local 8080` and then manually GET'ing the url works fine, so it's not a weird HTTP problem.
3. I have no trouble using node.js to connect to other hosts e.g. http://www.google.com

I expect the useful system information would include:

```
$ node -v
v0.9.11

$ uname -a
Darwin myhost.local 12.2.1 Darwin Kernel Version 12.2.1:
Thu Oct 18 12:13:47 PDT 2012; root:xnu-2050.20.9~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

$ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.8.2
BuildVersion:   12C3104

$ sudo  netstat -nalt | grep LISTEN | grep 8080
tcp6       0      0  ::1.8080  *.*    LISTEN
```

Does anyone have any idea what is going on here, and what a fix might be?

Comment: Do you get the same error if you use `localhost` instead of `myhost.local`?

Comment: Is something running on localhost:80 ?

Comment: @JohnnyHK, @Floby: The application being connected to is Google App Engine, and it is bound to `myhost`. Let me post my `netstat` output though - it may be illuminating

Comment: I was thinking that the get method wasn't parsing the port part correctly and was connecting to something else instead. Try as answered below.

Comment: Based on your `netstat`, your 8080 service is bound to the IPv6 localhost, not the IPv4 one.  That may be the issue.

Comment: @Floby Thanks, I had tried that as well, and have posted the results.

Comment: @JohnnyHK: I think you are on to something ...

Comment: What host name are you using in the program listening on port 8080? Is it server.listen(8080, "myhost.local") ?

Comment: @HectorCorrea: It's running Google App Engine's `dev_appserver2`, so I am not sure how it is binding to the address, but from the `netstat` output it seems to be binding on IPv6 `::1`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm going to post this here in case somebody else has the problem.

Bert Belder, Node.js mailing list:

> On your system "myhost.local" resolves to three different addresses
>   (127.0.0.1, ::1, and fe80::1). Node prefers ipv4 over ipv6 so it'll
>   try to connect to 127.0.0.1. Nothing is listening on 127.0.0.1:8080 so
>   the connect() syscall fails with ECONNREFUSED. Node doesn't retry with
>   any of the other resolved IPs - it just reports the error to you. A
>   simple solution would be to replace 'localhost' by the intended
>   destination ip address, '::1'.
>
> Whether this behavior is right is somewhat open for debate, but this
>   is what causes it.
>
> Bert

Comment: Thanks alessioalex. I am sorry, but I was remiss in mentioning that I tried every permutation of the `/etc/hosts` file, including a having just the `::1 localhost myhost.local`. To no avail.

Comment: I should note that the solution is to bind the server to IPv4, but that is of course the wrong solution. :)

Comment: "Node prefers ipv4 over ipv6" is definitely wrong behavior. See [RFC 6724](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6724).

Answer (score 3):

This stemmed from an issue with Node (though there are ways to work around it), as per the [discussion on nodejs/Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/nodejs/0W6UqKy_klk), as @alessioalex alluded in his answer. A useful comment per Bert Belder:

> there should be a getaddrinfo wrapper that returns more that just the first result

For example,

```
> require('dns').lookup('myhost.local', console.log)
{ oncomplete: [Function: onanswer] }
> null '127.0.0.1' 4
```

This is the first of multiple `getaddrinfo` results passed to Node. It seems that nodejs only uses the first item of the `getaddrinfo` call. Bert and Ben Noordhuis agreed in the Groups discussion that there should be a way to return more than just the first result with the `getaddrinfo` wrapper.

Contrast python, which returns all results from `getaddrinfo`:

```
>>> import socket
>>> socket.getaddrinfo("myhost.local", 8080)
[(30, 2, 17, '', ('::1', 8080, 0, 0)),
 (30, 1, 6, '',  ('::1', 8080, 0, 0)),
 (2, 2, 17, '',  ('127.0.0.1', 8080)),
 (2, 1, 6, '',   ('127.0.0.1', 8080)),
 (30, 2, 17, '', ('fe80::1%lo0', 8080, 0, 1)),
 (30, 1, 6, '',  ('fe80::1%lo0', 8080, 0, 1))]
```

Answer (score 0):

does this work?

```
var http = require('http');
var options = {
  host: 'myhost.local',
  port: 8080,
  path: '/'
};

http.get(options, function (res) { 
  console.log("RES" + res) 
}).on('error', function (e) { 
  console.log("Error:", e) 
});
```

Comment: Thanks Manuel. That is effectively the same as `require('url').parse("http://myhost.local:8080/")`, which is what `http.get` calls when it is passed a string. I have updated my question to reflect this for clarity.